# Segfault-Iterative insert in BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a code to insert a new element in the BST iteratively. When I try to execute the code, I get a segfault. Can someone look over the code and help me correct it?

```
bool insert2(int item)
{
    BstNode *parent;
    BstNode *root=new BstNode;
    cout<<root->data;
    cout<<"\n";
    BstNode *ptr;
    int ctr=0;

    //cout<<root->data;
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        BstNode *temp=new BstNode;
        temp->data=item;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        root=temp;
        //cout<<root->data;
        return true;

    } 
    else
    {
        ptr=root;
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {
            ctr=ctr+1;
            cout<<ctr;
            if (ptr->data==item)
            {
                cout<<ptr->data;
                return false;
            }

            if (item < ptr->data)
            {
                parent=ptr;
                ptr=ptr->left;

            } 
            else
            {
                parent=ptr;
                ptr=ptr->right;
            }

        }
        BstNode *add=new BstNode;
        add->data = item;
        add->left= NULL;
        add->right= NULL;
        return true;
    }
}
```

on editing out the root-> data part, the code would go into the first if block and return true, which makes me guess that my problem lies somewhere in the deceleration.

Comment: Paste the constructor for `BstNode`

Comment: struct BstNode {
 int data; 
 BstNode* left;
 BstNode* right;
};

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar That is not a constructor.

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar Why are you creating a new root at the start of this function?  What if `insert2` is called 10 times?  Are you going to create 10 root nodes?

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how to access the root of the BST without passing a pointer to it in the function arguments. Can you suggest some other way so that  I can have the *root point to the root of the BST?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that you are doing wrong.  First of all, as PaulMcKenzie has pointed out, you should not be creating the root at the beginning of the function.  If the BST does not start out empty, the root already exists and you do not want to create a new one.  Instead, the root should be a public variable (which would only allow you to have one BST), or the function should take a pointer to the root as one of the parameters.  It certainly does not make sense that you create the root and then test it to see if it is NULL.  Unless you ran out of memory, it would not be NULL right after you created it.

Another problem with your code is that after you find the appropriate location in the BST, you create the new node, but do not attach it to the tree.  Instead, you might want to insert the following lines after you initialize `add`:

```
if(item < parent->data)
    parent->left = add;
else
    parent->right = add;
```

As far as the fact that you get a seg-fault every time you call the function, it is probably because, when you declare `root`, you do not initialize its `right` and `left` pointers to NULL. Therefore, the while loop does not stop when it reaches `root->left` or `root->right`.  When you try to deference `ptr` later in the loop, you are deferencing an uninitialized pointer, resulting in a seg-fault.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still looking for a way to access the BST without passing a pointer to the root in the function argument.Can you suggest some way in which I can do that?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, if do not allow more than one BST, you can make the pointer to the root a global variable (by declaring it outside of the body of the function).  Otherwise, you will have to pass a pointer to the BST as a parameter.  After all, how would your function know which BST to insert to if you do not pass it a pointer?